# not able to pass parameters to a function in another class(in another python file) - the code runs but values are not passed

Tags: python, tkinter

My aim is to learn creating a widget that can do Create/Read/Update/Delete (CRUD) operations on a simple Employee db.

I am attaching two files widget.py and dbcalls.py the second interacts with the sqlite db. The widget.py file creates the widget, receives data from the user with the help of textboxes and the relevant buttons.

I am doing a Create call to the dbcalls.Create() function with employeeId, employeeName and employeeSalary. But these values are not received in the dbcalls.Create function  not sure why (parameter passing is not working)

```
#File1 - widget.py
import tkinter as tk

from dbcalls import *

class Application(tk.Frame):
    eId = ""
    eName = ""
    eSalary = ""
    empData = [eId,eName,eSalary]

    def __init__(self,master=None):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()        
        self.createWidgets()

    def Create(self):
        self.getData()
        print ("Before odbc.create()")
        self.odbc.Create(self.eId,self.eName,self.eSalary)

   # def Read(self):
    #    self.odbc.Read(empData)

    #def Update(self):
     #   self.odbc.Update(empData)

    #def Delete(self):
     #   self.odbc.Delete(empData)

    def getData(self):
        self.odbc = dbcalls()
        eId = str(self.eIdValue.get())
        eName = str(self.eNameValue.get())
        eSalary = str(self.eSalaryValue.get())
        empData = [eId,eName,eSalary]
        print ("empData is ", empData)

    def createWidgets(self):
        #empData Details
        self.eIdLabel = tk.Label(self, text='Employee Id')
        self.eIdValue= tk.Entry(self)
        self.eIdLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.eIdValue.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.eNameLabel = tk.Label(self,text='Employee Name')
        self.eNameValue = tk.Entry(self)
        self.eNameLabel.grid(row=1,column=0) 
        self.eNameValue.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.eSalaryLabel = tk.Label(self, text='Employee Salary')
        self.eSalaryValue= tk.Entry(self)
        self.eSalaryLabel.grid(row=2,column=0) 
        self.eSalaryValue.grid(row=2,column=1)

        #CRUD Buttons
        #odbc = dbcalls()
        self.CreateButton = tk.Button(self,text='Create', command=self.Create)
        self.CreateButton.grid(row=3,column=0)

        #self.ReadButton = tk.Button(self,text='Read', command= self.Read)
        #self.ReadButton.grid(row=3,column=1)

        #self.UpdateButton = tk.Button(self,text='Update', command=self.Update)
        #self.UpdateButton.grid(row=3,column=2)

        #self.DeleteButton = tk.Button(self,text='Delete', command=self.Delete)
        #self.DeleteButton.grid(row=3,column=3) 

        #self.ExitButton = tk.Button(self,text='Exit', command=self.Exited)
        #self.ExitButton.grid(row=3,column=4)


    def Exited(self):
        print ('Exit Button Pressed')
        #print (self.employee)
        self.quit()


c = Application()
c.master.title('CRUD Operations')
c.mainloop()
 # dbcalls.py File Below
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jul 29 16:06:12 2019

@author: CGDELL23
"""
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import sys

class dbcalls:
    def __init__(self):        
        self.eId = ""
        self.eName = ""
        self.eSalary = ""
        self.empData = [self.eId, self.eName,self.eSalary]

    def createConn(self):
        try:
            conn = None
            db = "C:\\Users\CGDELL23\Desktop\python\wm910.db"
            conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        except Error as e:
            print (e)
        return conn

    def closeConn(self,conn):
        conn.close



    def Read(self,eId,eName,eSalary):
        cN=self.createConn()
        cR=cN.cursor()
        cR.execute("select * from Employee where employee =?", eId)
        rows = cR.fetchmany(100)
        for row in rows:
            print (rows)
        self.closeConn(cN)

    def Create(self,eId,eName,eSalary):
        self.eId = eId
        self.eName = eName
        self.eSalary = eSalary
        print ("In dbcalls.Create()",self.empData)
        cN=self.createConn()
        try:
            cR=cN.cursor()
            cR.execute("insert into Employee (EmployeeId,EmployeeName, EmployeeSalary) values (?,?,?) ", ('CG007','Patnam','450000'))
            print ("Before Commit")
            cN.commit()
            print ("After Commit")
            self.closeConn(cN)
        except Error as e:
            print (e)
            sys.exit(1)

    def Update(self,eId,eName,eSalary):
        cN=self.createConn()
        cR=cN.cursor()
        cR.execute("update Employee SET EmpName = %s, EmpSalary=%s WHERE EmpId = %s", eName,eSalary, eId)
        cN.commit()
        self.closeConn(cN)

    def delete(self,eId):
        cN=self.createConn()
        cR=cN.cursor()
        cR.execute("delete from Employee where empId = %s", eId)
        cN.commit()
        self.closeConn(cN)



As you can see below in the dbcalls.Create() function the empData is all nulls. Even though the EmployeeId,EmployeeName and EmployeeSalary were successfully received in Create function of the Application class and passed to the Create function in the dbcalls class.
```

**Not sure why are the parameters in the application class are not passed to the dbcalls class.**

```
    >>>runfile('C:/Users/CGDELL23/CRUDperations/widget.py', wdir='C:/Users/CGDELL23/CRUDOperations')
    empData is  ['CG007', 'Patnam', '450000']
    Before odbc.create()
    In dbcalls.Create() ['', '', '']
    UNIQUE constraint failed: Employee.EmployeeId
    An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

    SystemExit: 1
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve]. To reproduce the problem do we need a database at all? If the problem is passing parameters around, we shouldn't need a database. And do we really need all four CRUD functions _for the purpose of this question_?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with 'other files'. `eId` etc are defined at class level inside Application as empty strings, and are never updated.

You don't seem to need those as class or instance attributes at all, though. You should probably just return them from `getData`.

```
def Create(self):
    eId, eName, eSalary = self.getData()
    print ("Before odbc.create()")
    self.odbc.Create(eId, eName, eSalary)


def getData(self):
    self.odbc = dbcalls()
    eId = str(self.eIdValue.get())
    eName = str(self.eNameValue.get())
    eSalary = str(self.eSalaryValue.get())
    return (eId,eName,eSalary)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #This is a working piece of code for CRUD operations on a Sqlite Employee db
     #Just that you know people coming from Java please don't split your code to be contained into many  classes. Code is all put into one file and one class
     # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    #Created on Fri Jul 12 15:50:54 2019

    #@author: CGDELL23
    import tkinter as tk#There are many tools used for creating UI in python and tkinter is one - there are other UI tools also

    import sqlite3 #This is a opensource relational db which can be used with python
    from sqlite3 import Error
    import sys     #This is the System package -which talks about stacktrace and the like

    class dbcalls:
               
        def createConn(self):
            try:
                conn = None
                db = "C:\\Users\CGDELL23\Desktop\python\wm910.db"
                conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
            except Error as e:
                print (e)
            return conn
         
        def closeConn(self,conn):
            conn.close
         
        def Read(self,eId,eName,eSalary):
            try:
                cN=self.createConn()
                print("In dbcalls.Read()", eId,eName,eSalary)
                cR=cN.cursor()
                cR.execute("select * from Employee where EmployeeId = ?", (eId,))#it expects a tuple so have a , after eId
                rows = cR.fetchmany(100)# As there are many records in a selection we have to use fetchmany()
                for row in rows:
                    print (row)
                cN.commit()
                cR.close()
                self.closeConn(cN)
            except Error as e:
                print (e)
                self.closeConn(cN)
        
        def Create(self,eId,eName,eSalary):
            print ("In dbcalls.Create()",eId,eName, eSalary)
            cN=self.createConn()
            try:
                cR=cN.cursor()
                cR.execute("insert into Employee (EmployeeId,EmployeeName, EmployeeSalary) values (?,?,?) ", (eId,eName,eSalary))
                cN.commit()
                cR.close()
                self.closeConn(cN)
            except Error as e:
                print (e)
                self.closeConn(cN)
                
        def Update(self,eId,eName,eSalary):
            cN=self.createConn()
            try:
                cR=cN.cursor()
                print ("In dbcalls.Update()",eId,eName, eSalary)
                cR.execute("update Employee SET EmployeeName = ?, EmployeeSalary = ? WHERE EmployeeId = ?", (eName,eSalary, eId))
                cN.commit()
                cR.close()
                self.closeConn(cN)
            except Error as e:
                print (e)
                self.closeConn(cN)
                       
        def Delete(self,eId,eName,eSalary):
            cN=self.createConn()
            try:
                cR=cN.cursor()
                print ("In dbcalls.Delete()",eId,eName,eSalary)
                cR.execute("delete from Employee where EmployeeId = ?", (eId,))#it expects a tuple so have a , after eId
                cN.commit()
                cR.close()
                self.closeConn(cN)
            except Error as e:
                print (e)
                self.closeConn(cN)

    class Application(tk.Frame):#This is frame to position all your widgets
        eId = ""
        eName = ""
        eSalary = ""
        empData = [eId,eName,eSalary]
        odbc = dbcalls()
            
        def __init__(self,master=None):#This is a reserved method like constructor in java to initialize attributes
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
            self.grid()        
            self.createWidgets()

        def getData(self):        
            eId = str(self.eIdValue.get())
            eName = str(self.eNameValue.get())
            eSalary = str(self.eSalaryValue.get())
            return (eId,eName,eSalary)
            
        def Create(self):
            eId,eName,eSalary = self.getData()
            print ("Before odbc.create()")
            self.odbc.Create(eId,eName,eSalary)
            
        def Read(self):
            eId,eName,eSalary = self.getData()
            self.odbc.Read(eId,eName,eSalary)
            
        def Update(self):
            eId,eName,eSalary = self.getData()
            self.odbc.Update(eId,eName,eSalary)
            
        def Delete(self):
            eId,eName,eSalary = self.getData()
            self.odbc.Delete(eId,eName,eSalary)
           
        def Exit(self):
            print ('Exit Button Pressed')
            sys.exit(0)
            
        def createWidgets(self):#This section talks about positioning the widgets in the Frame
            #empData Details
            self.eIdLabel = tk.Label(self, text='Employee Id')
            self.eIdValue= tk.Entry(self)
            self.eIdLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)
            self.eIdValue.grid(row=0,column=1)
            
            self.eNameLabel = tk.Label(self,text='Employee Name')
            self.eNameValue = tk.Entry(self)
            self.eNameLabel.grid(row=1,column=0) 
            self.eNameValue.grid(row=1,column=1)
            
            self.eSalaryLabel = tk.Label(self, text='Employee Salary')
            self.eSalaryValue= tk.Entry(self)
            self.eSalaryLabel.grid(row=2,column=0) 
            self.eSalaryValue.grid(row=2,column=1)
            
            #CRUD Buttons
            self.CreateButton = tk.Button(self,text='Create', command=self.Create)
            self.CreateButton.grid(row=3,column=0)
            
            self.ReadButton = tk.Button(self,text='Read', command= self.Read)
            self.ReadButton.grid(row=3,column=1)
            
            self.UpdateButton = tk.Button(self,text='Update', command=self.Update)
            self.UpdateButton.grid(row=3,column=2)
            
            self.DeleteButton = tk.Button(self,text='Delete', command=self.Delete)
            self.DeleteButton.grid(row=3,column=3) 
            
            self.ExitButton = tk.Button(self,text='Exit', command=self.Exit)
            self.ExitButton.grid(row=3,column=4)
            
        
            
    c = Application()
    c.master.title('CRUD Operations')
    c.mainloop()#This is tkinter's - public static void main() of Java
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.